# Android won't mount SD card after using link2sd

Tags: root-access, partitions, link2sd

I'm extremely inexperienced when it comes to using link2sd but my basic understanding before using it was this:

I partition my 16GB SD card to FAT32 (about 12GB) and Ext2(about 4GB), link2sd uses the second partition of Ext2, and the first partition can be used by my phone to store other stuff like videos, photos, etc.

So I partition my SD card using AParted and it is successful. In Link2SD I chose "Recreate mount scripts" and select Ext2 as the "file system of my SD card's second partition". Then I am also able to successfully link my apps to my Ext2 partition in my SD card. However something really weird happens. Android won't mount my SD card so I can't access it and store stuff in it even though Link2SD can!

Is this the way how link2sd works? The other partition of your sd card becomes useless? Or am I doing something wrong.. :/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your phone a Samsung Galaxy J7 Pro 2017 (SM-J730)? It seems like I have the same issue. I have described it with more detail in https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/196678/samsung-galaxy-j7-pro-2017-sm-j730gm-doesnt-seem-to-support-partitioned-sd-ca